# How to get a simple python function into a web app

Tags: python, function, web-applications

I created a simple python function with Jupyter Notebook as follows:

```
data = {'Names' : ['Bob','Ann','Max','Ron','Fin','Eric']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def name():
    print(df.Names.sample(1).iloc[0])
```

Calling this function prints a random name from my DataFrame:

```
name()
# Ann
```

Now I would like to create a **web app** with this function in order to share a link with others so that they can use my function. A simple button for users to get a random name will be enough.

What's the most efficient way to achieve this for someone like me with no experience in HMTL, Java or other programming languages?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to continue working in Python, you could try [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/)

Comment: The [quickstart section](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/) especially

Comment: Thanks. Can you show the specific code to do this?